# IAccessible: Get Active url with Access violation

Tags: delphi

I'm with a problem for show my Form1 and listen the active url in on browser. In code following, after the test with showmessage function, apper an Acess violation in my project as on following images:

[IMAGE_!](http://prntscr.com/51vh96) and
[IMAGE_2](http://prntscr.com/51vkdn)
[image]

Here is my code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, { MSAAIntf, } Oleacc, ActiveX;

type
  HWINEVENTHOOK = DWORD;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  Memo1: TMemo;
  vHook: HWINEVENTHOOK = 0;
  Eventos: Boolean = false;
  UrlAtiva, UrlVelha: WideString;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure WinEventProc(HWINEVENTHOOK: THandle; event: DWORD; hwnd: hwnd;
  idObject, idChild: Longint; idEventThread, dwmsEventTime: DWORD); stdcall;

var
  vAccObj: IAccessible;
  varChild: OleVariant;
  vWSName, vWSValue: WideString;
  ClassName: String;
  Acesso: HResult;

begin
  vAccObj := nil;
  Acesso := AccessibleObjectFromEvent(hwnd, idObject, idChild, vAccObj,
    varChild);
  SetLength(ClassName, 255);
  SetLength(ClassName, GetClassName(hwnd, pchar(ClassName), 255));

  IF (Acesso = S_OK) and (vAccObj <> nil) THEN
  BEGIN
    vAccObj.Get_accName( { CHILDID_SELF } varChild, vWSName);
    vAccObj.Get_accValue( { CHILDID_SELF } varChild, vWSValue);
  END;

  IF (pchar(ClassName) = 'Chrome_WidgetWin_1') AND (Eventos = true) AND
    (vWSName = 'Address and search bar') AND (vWSValue <> '<null>') THEN

    UrlAtiva := vWSValue;

  IF (UrlAtiva <> UrlVelha) THEN

  BEGIN
    UrlVelha := UrlAtiva;
    Memo1.Lines.Add(UrlAtiva);
  end;

  vAccObj._Release;
end;

procedure Unhook;

begin
  if (vHook = 0) then
    Exit;

  UnhookWinEvent(vHook);
  CoUninitialize;
end;

procedure Hook;

begin
  if (vHook <> 0) then
    Exit;

  CoInitialize(nil);
  vHook := SetWinEventHook(EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS, EVENT_OBJECT_VALUECHANGE, 0,
    WinEventProc, 0, 0, WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS);
end;

function Thread_Infinite(navegador: Pointer = nil): DWORD; stdcall;

var

  wH: array of THandle;
  wR: DWORD;
  Msg: TMSG;
  leave: Boolean;

begin
  wH := navegador;
  leave := false;
  Hook;

  repeat
    wR := MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, wH, false, INFINITE, QS_ALLEVENTS);

    case wR of

      WAIT_ABANDONED:
        ;
      WAIT_FAILED:
        ;
      WAIT_OBJECT_0:
        begin
          leave := true;
          break;
        end;

      WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1:
        while PeekMessage(Msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) do
        begin
          TranslateMessage(Msg);
          DispatchMessage(Msg);
        end;
    end;
    break;

  Until not leave;
  Unhook;
  Result := 0;
end;

function inicia_tudo: integer;

var
  szFileName: array [0 .. 100] of char;
  szModuleName: array [0 .. 19] of char;
  iSize: integer;
  threadId: DWORD;
  Stop, Thread: THandle;
begin
  StrPCopy(szModuleName, 'Project1');
  iSize := GetModuleFileName(GetModuleHandle(szModuleName), szFileName,
    SizeOf(szFileName));
  if iSize > 0 then
  begin
    ShowMessage(StrPas(szFileName));
    Eventos := true;
  end;

  Stop := CreateEvent(nil, true, false, nil);
  Thread := CreateThread(nil, 0, (Pointer(Thread_Infinite)), (Pointer(Stop)),
    0, threadId);

  SetEvent(Stop);

  WaitForSingleObject(Thread, 5000);

  CloseHandle(Thread);
  CloseHandle(Stop);

  Result := 0;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  inicia_tudo;
end;

end.
```

Comment: `vAccObj` is an interface, it will call `_Release` when it is no longer referenced, don't call `._Release` yourself.

Comment: Second problem is `Memo1.Lines.Add`. This code must execute in the context of the main thread, use `Synchronize`to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something more like this instead:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure AddUrlToMemo;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses
  { MSAAIntf, } Oleacc, ActiveX;

{$R *.dfm}

type
  HWINEVENTHOOK = THandle;

var
  UrlVelha: WideString;
  Thread: THandle = 0;
  ThreadId: DWORD = 0;

procedure WinEventProc(hWinEventHook: HWINEVENTHOOK; event: DWORD; hwnd: HWND;
  idObject, idChild: Longint; idEventThread, dwmsEventTime: DWORD); stdcall;
var
  vAccObj: IAccessible;
  varChild: OleVariant;
  vWSName, vWSValue: WideString;
  ClassName: String;
  Acesso: HResult;
begin
  SetLength(ClassName, 255);
  SetLength(ClassName, GetClassName(hwnd, PChar(ClassName), 255));

  if (ClassName = 'Chrome_WidgetWin_1') then
  begin
    Acesso := AccessibleObjectFromEvent(hwnd, idObject, idChild, vAccObj, varChild);
    If (Acesso = S_OK) and (vAccObj <> nil) then
    begin
      vAccObj.Get_accName( { CHILDID_SELF } varChild, vWSName);
      if (vWSName = 'Address and search bar') then
      begin
        vAccObj.Get_accValue( { CHILDID_SELF } varChild, vWSValue);
        if (vWSValue <> '') and (vWSValue <> '<null>') and (UrlVelha <> vWSValue) then
        begin
          UrlVelha := vWSValue;
          TThread.Synchronize(nil, Form1.AddUrlToMemo);
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

function Thread_Infinite(param: Pointer): DWORD; stdcall;
var
  Msg: TMSG;
  vHook: HWINEVENTHOOK;
begin
  CoInitialize(nil);

  vHook := SetWinEventHook(EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS, EVENT_OBJECT_VALUECHANGE, 0,
    @WinEventProc, 0, 0, WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS);

  while GetMessage(Msg, 0, 0, 0) do
  begin
    TranslateMessage(Msg);
    DispatchMessage(Msg);
  end;

  if (vHook <> 0) then
    UnhookWinEvent(vHook);

  CoUninitialize;
  Result := 0;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Thread := CreateThread(nil, 0, @Thread_Infinite, nil, 0, ThreadId);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (ThreadId <> 0) then
    PostThreadMessage(ThreadId, WM_QUIT, 0, 0);
  if (Thread <> 0) then
  begin
    repeat
      if (WaitForSingleObject(Thread, 5000) <> WAIT_TIMEOUT) then
        Break;
      CheckSynchronize;
    until False;
    CloseHandle(Thread);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.AddUrlToMemo;
begin
  if (Memo1 <> nil) and (not (csDestroying in ComponentState)) then
    Memo1.Lines.Add(UrlVelha);
end;

end.
```